# Rails Nested routes with ajax

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, nested-routes

Let's say I have a URL like this:

```
http://domain.com/projects/14/phases/30
```

But I'm loading the phases#show action into a div on my projects#show view via :remote => true links.

I would a user to be able to visit `http://domain.com/projects/14/phases/30` and have the projects#show view render and auto-load the view for phases/30 into the specified div.

I just need a nudge in the right direction. I'm having trouble finding anything about this issue online.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can run ajax request to that action on page load

First off all pass current url into js (Or you can use another method of passing data into js from [this episode](http://railscasts.com/episodes/324-passing-data-to-javascript)).

```
-# app/views/phases/show.html.haml
#content{:"data-url" => project_phases_path(@project, @phase)}
```

And run request to that url.

```
// app/assets/javascripts/phases.js.coffee
jQuery ->
  $.ajax
    url: $("#content").data("url")
```